# Django model manager error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to override the all() method, to filter the querySet, but it throws an error:

> typeError: module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

This is my modelmanager

```
class PostManager(models.manager):
def all(self):
    return super(PostManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())
```

and this is the model

```
class post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I think you want to inherit from `models.Manager`, not `models.manager`. And restricting `objects.all()` might not be such a great idea, really - you'd be better defining a `published()` method on your manager and leave `all` alone.

Comment: Oh an yes do yourself (and everyone that might have to work on your code) a favour: capitalize your classes names (ie `Post` not `post`).

Comment: thank you very much, it works now,  can you please explain what you mean by defining a published() , do you mean replacing the "all" in my code by "published"

Comment: did that solve the problem ?

Comment: sure it did (Y)

Comment: "can you please explain what you mean by defining a published() , do you mean replacing the "all" in my code by "published"" : yes, exactly. Lots of things in Django implicitly rely on `objects.all()` returning the whole queryset. Using custom managers (and eventually custom querysets) to factor out common use cases (like yours) is actually a good thing, but messing with the `all()` method is definitly not a good idea (been here, done that, still have the tee-shirt <g>).